# How to readstream data from a specific folder onwards in azure databricks

Tags: xml, azure, pyspark, spark-streaming, azure-databricks

I need to know in read stream how can I start reading files from a specific folder.In my storage account data is coming from 2019 yyyymmdd format, I need to pick the data from 2022 year and with the help of checkpoint streaming will take care new month data.

[image]

```py
checkpointPath = '/mnt/checkpointasnmod1'

schemapath = '/FileStore/tables/scema-1.txt'

inputPath ='/mnt/ASN-1.0/*/*'

outputPath ='/mnt/rawoutputpartially1'

schemaJson = spark.read.text(schemapath).first()[0]
schemaStruct = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(schemaJson))

df =spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").option("cloudFiles.useNotifications","false").option("cloudFiles.validateOptions","false").option("cloudFiles.format","text").option("wholetext","true").option("modifiedAfter","2022-12-20T13:00:00").load(inputPath,schema=None).writeStream.trigger(once=True).outputMode("append").queryName(inputPath).foreachBatch(transformasn).option("checkpointLocation",checkpointPath).start()
```

This is not giving any result, & if I will try to read from 2018 till date data size is almost 25gb which is giving out of memory error. Could any one help in order to read from 2022/* which property can help in readstream.

Answer (score 0):

In databricks  to filter files with specific folder you can use folder name with `*` to take all similar folders `/2022*/*`

**Example**

```py
demodf=(spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
        .option("cloudFiles.useNotifications","false")
        .option("cloudFiles.validateOptions","false")
        .option("cloudFiles.format","text")
        .option("wholetext","true")
        .option("modifiedAfter","2022-12-20T13:00:00")
        .load("/mnt/df1/2022*/*",schema=None))
```

`/2022*/*`  it will read data from all folders starting with 2022 and all files in it.

**Execution:**

[image]

Comment: How does it help when 2023 year will come does it take automatically?

Comment: no, it will not take it automatically you have to do it manually by specify the year which you want to filter.